# Write 199319989756262759279209 = 5x + y, where x and y are integers

Tags: functions, algorithm

$\frac{199319989756262759279209}{5} $ = $ 3.9864\times 10^{22}$
according to *Mathematica*, but I would like to see this number exactly in decimal form (not in scientific notation). I'm attempting to use the Euclidean Algorithm and Extended Euclidean algorithm to get a final result, and precision and accuracy both are very much needed. This number truncated would give me x and then y is simply the difference of that large number and `5 x`. Unless there's an easier way to do the Euclidean algorithm in *Mathematica* as well that'd be nice.

Comment: `but I would like to see this number exactly in decimal form (not in scientific notation)` You can use AccountingForm? `n1 = 199319989756262759279209; AccountingForm[N[n1/5, 30], {30, 29}]` gives `39863997951252551855841.8000000` (just remember, this is only a wrapper.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @m_goldberg ah I was writing that in an answer when you commented. I think it is good to have an "official" answer though.

Comment: I overlooked this function for a long time and now suddenly I saw it because it was an option for the autocomplete. I have very often used `Mod` and `Quotient` together, being a little frustrated that basically the same computation was being done twice. I learned something today :)

Comment: Though I guess finding the remainder by simply subtracting the quotient from the original number is not inefficient at all.

Comment: @Nasser.  In this particular case, `AccountingForm` suffices, provided we interpret  ....8000000 as repeating zeros, forever.  `AccountingForm ` will not generally allow for the exact representation of a fraction.  The reason is that Mathematica does not provide a built-in notation for "repeating tails" of decimals.

Comment: Some thoughts on how to extend Mathematica to cover decimal representations of fractions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200617/how-can-i-make-a-working-repeating-decimal-representation-of-a-rational-number

Comment: With respect to Euclid's Algorithm, there's `ExtendedGCD` and `Solve[eqn, vars, Integers]`.  [`GCD` uses Euclid's Algorithm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#31613) among other things.  None of these show the steps of Euclid's Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

To find the x and y, we can simply do

```
{x,y} = QuotientRemainder[199319989756262759279209, 5]
```

> {39863997951252551855841, 4}

The Euclidean algorithm seems like overkill for this case. The operations needed to calculate this have been well optimized and your computer probably has hardware to do such divisions. See [wiki:division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) for a glimpse of what algorithms are actually used.

**Restorable numbers**

In reply to comments by DavidCarraher below, I have to add the warning that just storing the x and y is not enough information to restore the result of the fraction. You also need to store the number you divided by. Here are two solutions

```
quotientRepresentation[num_, base_] :=
 {QuotientRemainder[num, base],
   base}

quotientFracRepresentation[num_, 
  base_] :=
 {#1, #2/base} & @@ QuotientRemainder[num, base]
```

We then have

```
quotientRepresentation[199319989756262759279209, 5]
```

> {{39863997951252551855841, 4}, 5}

and

```
quotientFracRepresentation[199319989756262759279209, 5]
```

> {39863997951252551855841, 4/5}

Note that it is possible that information about the original number is lost when using `quotientFracRepresentation`. The remainder is not divisible by the "base", but they may have a common divisor.

To solve this, we can use`HoldForm` like this

```
quotientFracHoldFormRepresentation[num_, base_] := 
 Function[Null, {#1, HoldForm[Rational[#2, base]]}, HoldAll] @@ 
  QuotientRemainder[num, base]
```

Examples

```
quotientFracBoxRepresentation[10, 4]
```

> {2,2/4}

```
quotientFracHoldFormRepresentation[199319989756262759279210, 4]
```

> {49829997439065689819802,2/4}

**Full emphasis on notation**

We can also take this all the way I suppose

```
quotientHoldFormRepresentation[num_, base_] :=

 Function[Null, HoldForm@Plus[#1, Rational[#2, base]], HoldAll] @@ 
  QuotientRemainder[num, base]
```

Example

```
quotientHoldFormRepresentation[199319989756262759279210, 4]
```

> 49829997439065689819802+2/4

```
quotientHoldFormRepresentation[199319989756262759279210, 4]//FullForm
```

> HoldForm[Plus[49829997439065689819802,Rational[2,4]]]

Now, to retrieve the result of division (for Mathematica to work with), simply do

```
quotientHoldFormRepresentation[199319989756262759279210, 
  4] // ReleaseHold
```

> 99659994878131379639605/2

Comment: Also, we should remember that in _Mathematica_. we can write `{x, y} = QuotientRemainder[199319989756262759279209, 5]`

Comment: Careful. The quotient plus remainder does not uniquely determine a number.  Consider this: `QuotientRemainder[9,4] = {2,1}`.  `QuotientRemainder[15,7] = {2,1}`.  But 9/4 does not equal 15/7. We might alternatively say that the QuotientRemainder function is a one-to-many mapping and hence not invertible.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I do not think the OP asked for this. From the notation 39863997951252551855841.8000000 the original number can also not be reconstructed, unless of course you know we have divided by 5 (which is also enough information to reconstruct the number from the quotient and the remainder).

Comment: I was referring to your answer, which is not a useful representation of the rational number expressed through the given fraction. (Btw, the original number can be reconstructed from the decimal if it is made clear, typically by a vinculum or an ellipsis, that the zero repeats ad infinitum.)

Comment: @DavidCarraher ahh, I see what you mean now. Indeed it is a pitfall to think that the rational number could be reproduced from this, good point. I will edit

Comment: Your entry about preserving the quotient is akin to expressing a (non-integral) quotient as a mixed fraction.  This is rather close to the form the OP used in his title: `199319989756262759279209 = 5x + y.`

Comment: Isn't `QuotientRemainder` the first step in the Euclidean Algorithm? :)  The next step, in this specific case, would be to realize you're done (1 divides the remainder).  The only short cut is that we realize from the start that we will be done after one step.  Certainly it seems exaggerated to call it the Eu. Alg., also obfuscating since your direct way seems clearer; but in terms of actual calculations, EA is not much extra.  Cheers!

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you for commenting, this is a nice subject to think about and one I feel I should grasp. I was certainly confused and didn't dare to claim with certainty that division was not simply done by using the Euclidean Algorithm. However, the wiki link I provided states that the Euclidean Algorithm is not really suitable for division. In [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_repeated_subtraction), the claim is made: "Although very simple, it takes Ω(Q) steps, and so is exponentially slower than even slow division algorithms like long division".

Comment: @MichaelE2 so I guess the term overkill is suitable in the sense that indeed the problem can be solved this way, but if we realize that we are solving a specific subproblem, there is much to be gained :) (except that we really only have to just use MMA functions instead of our own algorithms :P).

Comment: @Michael E2 Yes, `QuotientRemainder` is the first step in Euclid's Algorithm. The case at hand is simple. There are a couple of steps. The first division leaves a quotient of `39863997951252551855841` (if I copied correctly) and a remainder of `4`.  Then we must divide the former divisor, 5, by the current remainder, 4. That gives a "second integer quotient" of 1 and leaves a second remainder, 1. Next we need to divide the second divisor, 4, by the second remainder, 1. This generates a quotient of one and a remainder of zero.  It is only then that the algorithm terminates.

Comment: In other cases, the algorithm will require additional steps. But it will always terminate in a finite number of steps. It's interesting to think about how to express the original fraction as a continued fraction containing all of the "partial" quotients.

Comment: @MichaelE2 ah nevermind I guess. I am confused, but I have to do other stuff

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see that in the wiki page on the Euclidean algorithm, division is taken for granted. In the page about division algorithms, it is not, and it is claimed that the greatest common divisor algorithm by Euclid did the division by this inefficient subtraction. I suppose taking division for granted is the normal way of looking at things, so then you are right :)

Comment: @DavidCarraher  Oops, I guess I took a short-cut. It was before coffee.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Not a problem. Euclid's algorithm is, on the one hand, very simple; on the other is is rich and foundational. It's actually a shame that early mathematics education largely ignores it even though it provides an important bridge between Integers and Rational Numbers, which most elementary and middle school students will struggle with for years.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Euclid's Algorithm is the first proposition on arithmetic Euclid gives (in two parts, [VII.1](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII1.html). [VII.2](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII2.html)).  His approach is purely theoretical and no calculations are done whatsoever.  I doubt anyone knows how he actually computes division.  That integer division is equivalent to repeated subtraction is used in VII.1, but in VII.2 he uses division.  (The term in Greek for "divides" is "measures", as if laying measuring sticks end to end.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah yes. [the wiki section I mentioned before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_repeated_subtraction) makes the claim that this way of dividing was incorporated into the GCD algorithm. Maybe that is not completely accurate. I am curious now :), maybe I will read more of Euclid later. You made me enthousiastic :)

Answer (score 1):

My remarks are too long for a comment, so I'll place them here.

---

The title of the OP's entry, namely

> Write 199319989756262759279209 = 5x + y, where x and y are integers

is not the same as the question in the body, which asks for an exact decimal representation of

> 199319989756262759279209 / 5

Regarding the first question, there are integers, x, y, that make `199319989756262759279209 = 5x + y` true.  This will be true for any integer divisor, not just 5.  It follows from the division identity (or division algorithm): given positive integers `A`, `B`, there exist non-negative integers `Q`, `R`, where `R < B`, such that `A = BQ + R`.

Regarding the second question, if we accept a convention, such as a vinculum or ellipsis, for expressing the repeating "tail" of a decimal number, then we can express any fraction exactly as a decimal number. In the worst case scenario, the  magnitude of the "non-integer part"  of the quotient may require as many as `B-1` places, so the decimal expression is always finite, given that the divisor, `B`, is finite. (The decimal expression with vinculum stands for a non-terminating decimal, however. The case of a repeating zero is dealt with inconsistently.)