# Syntax question regarding Triple Integrals in Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration

```
Integrate[1, {z, 0, 5}, {x, -Sqrt[ 9 - y^2], Sqrt[ 9 - y^2]} , {y, -3, 3}]
```

> 60 Sqrt[9 - y^2]

How comes I am not getting a number for my final answer? This triple integral should evaluate to an exact number.

Comment: I edited your question for format. Read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 4):

Modify your code and notice the order of the integrals

```
Integrate[f[x, y, z], {z, zo, zf}, {x, a[y], b[y]}, {y, yo, yf}]
```

[image]

The first interval in the code `{z, zo, zf}` corresponds to the last integral.

From your question, it seems that you meant to compute

```
Integrate[1, {y, -3, 3}, {x, -Sqrt[9 - y^2], Sqrt[9 - y^2]}, {z, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Yes you are right! Hmm.. I would have thought it read from inner integral to outer integral but I couldn't be more wrong!

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, accept it: press the check mark below the big number the the top left and the check mark should turn green. You can upvote answers you like: check the up arrow on top of the number. Do the same to your other [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34037/8803). You might want to read [these FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/reputation), especially [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).